# Determining the area of a heart curve(2D)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I found out the area of a heart but I am not sure whether it is correct.

Can someone please check whether what I have done makes any sense at all.
[image]

The equation of a heart is shown below:

[image]

I first determined the jacobian(shown below):

[image]

[image]

Then I integrated the determinant of the  jacobian( shown below):

[image]

and I got:
$9π$/$4$ $units^3$

I sorry about the size of some of the formulas.

Comment: Small correction: You integrated the *determinant of the jacobian* but other than that it looks fine!

Comment: how else can I find out the area?

Comment: And this is the same thing that wolfram did when they determined the volume of a torus:                               http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html

Comment: @AnjaneyM: flawr is pointing out an error in word choice.  You said "I integrated the Jacobian"; but the Jacobian is actually a matrix.  The function you integrated—correctly and for the right reason—is the *determinant* of the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I misunderstood:) let me edit it

Comment: is it okay now?

Comment: Actually even though i did do it like this. I don't fully understand why it is like this because shouldn't the Jacobian determinant be multiplied with the function itself and then integrated?.

Comment: Check the $\dfrac {\partial y}{\partial t}$ term in the determinant. I think you want a $-1.5 sin(3t)$ not a $-3 sin(3t)$.

Comment: Thats true, I was meaning to put $3/2$. I will make changes to it

Comment: Another way to find the area is to evaluate the line integral $\int_C ydx$, parametrized by $t$ as you have above. You’ll need to be a bit careful about orientation to make sure that you get a positive value. That seems like it might be less messy.

Comment: What does the exponent of $3$ after “*units*” in your final answer mean? If it means “cubic units,” that’s either a typo or you’ve gone wrong somewhere since areas should be measured in square units.

Comment: Conceptually, you’re not really “integrating the Jacobian” to find the area bounded by the curve. You’re computing $\int_R1\;dA=\int_a^b\int_c^d 1\;dx\;dy$, where the bounds might be functions of $x$ and $y$. Changing coordinates to $r$ and $t$ introduces $|J|$ as a scale factor, but you’re still integrating the function $1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself some of the tedious algebraic and trigonometric manipulation by using Green’s Theorem. Since $\mathrm d(y\;\mathrm dx)=\mathrm dx\wedge\mathrm dy$, the integral $\int_Cy\;\mathrm dx$ gives the area of the region bounded by the closed curve $C$. In this case, we have $$\begin{align}
\int_Cy\;\mathrm dx &= \int_0^{2\pi}(3\cos t-2\cos{2t}-\frac12\cos{3t})\cdot6\sin^2t\cos t\;dt \\
&= \frac18\int_0^{2\pi}21-3\cos{2t}-12\cos{3t}-21\cos{4t}+12\cos{5t}+3\cos{6t}\;dt \\
&= \frac{21\pi}4.
\end{align}$$
Note that you can add the differential $\mathrm df$ of any differentiable function defined on the region to the integrand in order to simplify it without changing the value of the integral. A common choice is to integrate $\frac12(x\;\mathrm dy-y\;\mathrm dx)$, but that doesn’t really help here.